# Assigning length of a string to an integer: C++

Tags: c++, size, stdstring, unsigned-long-long-int

Using C++, I want to create a for loop as follows (`text` is a `std::string`):

```
 for(int i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
 {
```

Please could somebody help me understand why my complier (Xcode) requires me to initialise `i` as an unsigned long, and not as integer?

I assume the following, but I don't know, and I'd like to develop a better understanding: I believe it is to do with an integer having a maximum value of 2147483647, whereas an unsigned long has a maximum value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. Since a string can hold up to 4294967295 characters, the use of an integer is inappropriate since its maximum value couldn't represent the maximum length of a string?

Finally, is the unsigned long data type appropriate, or should I use a long int?

My amended for loop is as follows:

```
 for(unsigned long i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    }
```

or

```
for(long int i = text.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    }
```

Comment: do you get a compiler error? Please incldue it in the question

Comment: `texts.size()` returns an unsigned type. The real question: If you're enumerating the string in reverse order, why aren't you using `for (auto it = text.rbegin(); it != text.rend(); ++it)` , utilize the iterator as warranted, and be done with it?

Comment: No, I don't get a complier error. However, I get a warning: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Comment: `size()` returns `size_t`. Its easiest to use just that, but beware that then `i >= 0; i--` won't do any good

Comment: a warning is not the same as "my compiler wont let me", its rather "my compiler reminds me that most likely I should fix something"

Comment: `i = text.size()` makes `i` start out of bounds so you must use `i - 1` inside the loop and in that case, your condition should be `i > 0`. - Alternatively: `for(size_t i = text.size() - 1; i < text.size(); --i)`

Comment: Hi WhorzCraig, I'm working my way through a beginner course and haven't reached those functions as of yet; I will have a look though, cheers.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have made it clear. I'm completing a beginner course and thus far I'm only using basic operators. I understand that there are more efficient methods, however, for the task I have to complete, I'm required to use basic functions. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: `i >= 0` is always true for unsigned `i`

Comment: Sounds like the beginner course is teaching **advance techniques** (or the *to be avoided techniques*, except for experts with years of experience in the language and know when the advanced technique is warranted) rather than the **basic techniques** such as the one WhozCraig mentioned.

Comment: largest_prime_is_463035818: I see, thank you. Okay, I have a follow up question: If I proceed and compile, on this occasion the code functions because the length of the string is less than the maximum length of the integer. Even though we know the length of the string will never exceed the limits of the integer, is it okay to use the integer data type, or is it best practice to use a data type that matches the limits of the maximum string length?

Comment: In [C++ style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types) it is mentioned: *try to use iterators and containers rather than pointers and sizes, try not to mix signedness, and try to avoid unsigned types (except for representing bitfields or modular arithmetic). Do not use an unsigned type merely to assert that a variable is non-negative.*. If you can't use iterators here, use signed types. If needed, use *casting*  to avoid warnings.

Comment: Eljay: Using the length of a string to determine the number of for loop iterations is an advanced technique, surely not?

Comment: I didn't want to imply that you should not take warnings serious. not at all. Best is to treat them as errors and fix whatever made the compiler complain. Also, never say never, its always better to not write code that only works due to implicit assumptions. A string whose lenght exceeds the range of `int` is unlikely, but it is such kind of assumptions that can cause big trouble on the long run

Comment: Damien, you're a legend, thank you! This is exactly what I'm after. I already had the C++ Style Guide bookmarked, I really should have looked at this. Note to self: refer to the C++ style guide before asking questions. Thanks again.

Comment: Largest_Prime: I'll ensure I keep this in mind. I appreciate the help and pointers, thanks a lot.

Comment: tip: prepend the user name with an @ so they get notified. I saw your comment only by chance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::string::size()` returns an unsigned integer type (`std::size_t`). Changing the type of `i` is easy enough, but introduces another problem. With `i` being type `std::size_t` the loop condition is broken; by definition an unsigned type is *always* going to be `>= 0`

There are alternatives, the most direct being to modify the entire for-loop to:

1. Declare `i` as `std::size_t`
2. Move the decrement as a post-decrement in the condition check
3. Remove the increment step entirely.

The result looks like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = text.size(); i-- > 0;)
{
    // use text[i] here
}
```

This will enumerate within the loop body from `(text.size()-1)` through `0` inclusively, and break the loop thereafter. It will work even if the string is empty.

Note that such hijinks are a sign of a larger problem: using the wrong construct in the first place. `std::string` provides *reverse iterators* for walking the string content backward:

```
for (auto it = text.rbegin(); it != text.rend(); ++it)
{
    // use *it  to access each character in reverse order
}
```

Of these two methods, the second is preferred.

Comment: You missed the opportunity to use the "goes-to" operator: `i --> 0` :)

Comment: @eerorika lolz. That question on SO is a classic. "what's this odd operator `-->` ??" Still makes me smile.

Comment: @WhorzCraig I greatly appreciate you returning to provide this explanation, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, the `size()` member function of the `std::string` class returns a value of type `size_t`. The exact nature of this type will vary between platforms and compilers, but it will always be an *unsigned* type. Generally, it is equivalent to either `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int`.

So, to avoid the compiler warning about initialising your `int i`, you should declare that loop index as a `size_t` variable: `for (size_t i = text.size(); ...`.

However, as also noted in the comments, your loop test condition (`i >= 0`) is then no good, because, for any *unsigned* type, that condition can ***never*** be false. So, instead, you should change that condition to `i > 0`; you should also be sure that any access to your `test` elements based on that `i` variable should use the index value `i - 1` (rather than just `i`): the last element will be at `size - 1` and the first element will be at `0`, so your loop will hold for the following:

```cpp
for (size_t i = text.size(); i > 0; --i) {
    char element = text[i - 1]; // We need to offset our loop index by -1 ...
    // Do something with or to 'element'
    // ...
}
```